# Is there a version of the PHP array that is pass-by-reference?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I'm asking this because I'm working with a recursive function that generates a large array tree and the pass-by-copy aspect of the arrays are completely screwing with my head. I've tried using ArrayObject, but that's really an object, isn't it? None of the `array_keys` type array functions work with it, and `json_encode` doesn't understand that it's an array.

I'd like a version of the PHP `array` that feels, smells and looks like the normal array, but is pass-by-reference. Is there anything like that in PHP?

---

Woah woah hold up people; I'm well aware of the & symbol but that's what I'm trying to **avoid**. As my question specifies (^) I'm looking for a version of the PHP array that is pass-by-reference **by default**

Comment: This is not what you want I believ,e but it might help you a bit http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/09/php-serialization-and-recursion.html

Comment: @Codemonkey: There is no PHP Array version which is pass-by-reference in nature by default. You have to tell the PHP how to treat the Array and Stop downvoting to the correct answers.

Comment: That may or may not be true, but your answer would still not be correct

Comment: Sounds to me like your code is simply too complicated. If you can't wrap your head around manually passing by reference, I don't see how having it done automatically for you would be of any help, the behavior would still be the same.

Comment: Because I constantly have to check whether I'm passing a reference to an array or a reference to a reference. It doesn't take many passes before that becomes a pain. Obviously with an **object** I wouldn't have to worry about any of that anyway. Thusly; an array that behaves like an object would be the perfect solution

Comment: You can't pass "a reference to a reference". Specifying a function parameter as pass-by-reference just means that the variable in the caller will be modified. Whether that itself was passed by reference or not doesn't matter, the behavior doesn't change. PHP references are not C pointers, if that's what's confusing you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like a version of the PHP array that feels, smells and looks like
>   the normal array, but is pass-by-reference. Is there anything like
>   that in PHP?

No, There is nothing like that in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Json encode should be able to pass objects. But if you for some reason NEED an array, you can't use objects and then cast it as array before encoding to json?

```
<?php
$object = (object)array("number"=>1);
function addToTen($object){
    if($object->number<10){
        $object->number++;
        addToTen($object);
    }
}
addToTen($object);
echo json_encode((array)$object);
//echoes {"number":10} with or without casting it as an array
?>
```

You could also wrap your array in an object of course, like this:

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->a = array();
function fillUpArray($object){
    if(count($object->a)<10){
    $object->a[] = "someValue";
        fillUpArray($object);
    }
}
fillUpArray($object);
echo json_encode($object->a);
//echoes ["someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue","someValue"]
```

I must admit though I don't entirely get what you're trying to accomplish here :S

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the PHP manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: That is not a pass-by-reference version of the PHP array, that's just a way of passing a pointer instead of the value

Answer (score 0):

Stop using &references altogether, in php they get cumbersome pretty quickly, (being, unlike C pointers, almost transparent, the only way to check you're actually using a reference is by assigning junk to it and check the effect this has on a  tree) and you don't seem willing to handle that level of subtlety.

(Nor to wrap it with an [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), apparently)

Are you aware **objects ARE references**?
**Object-wrap** every aspect of your tree and your life will instantly get less miserable.

Comment: My final tree must be an array, unless I'd like to rewrite `json_encode`. I am well aware that objects are references, but I'm almost entirely positive that there's a low level object version of the array that acts like the normal array in every way, except that it will pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such built-in functionality in PHP that you ask. Also, you are quite reluctant to use references. Hmmm...you could send a request to the PHP dev team to include such stuff in PHP v6, along with unicode that is supposed to come, that would us all happy :).

However, can you use a class and assign your initial array to one of the class variables and then process it and get it back after the recursion. Not sure if that would work, but anyway here it is:

```
<?php
class noReference {
    public $myData;

    public function __construct( $data ) {
       $this->myData = $data; // this is your initial array.
    }

    // this function works on the myData array and changes it.
    public function myRecursiveFunction() {
       // your code here
       $this->myRecursiveFunction(); // called as per your logic
       // your code here
    }

    public function getData() {
       return $this->myData;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
       unset( $this->myData );
    }
}

$data = array(/*WHATEVER_PLEASES_YOU*/);
$noref = new noReference( $data );
// this will be your recuresive function
$noref->myRecursiveFunction();

//your data here
$result = $noref->getData();
?>
```

Let me know if this works. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

you can force php to pass things by reference by adding an `&`-sign to the parameter. [read the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) for more information.

Comment: I know, but there's so many "passes" back and forth and references to all the arrays that I can't wrap my head around it. That's why I'm looking for a simpler solution